# Use url as filename

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, decoding

I have an url in python, and want to convert this to a suitable filename. I started with replacing "/" with "_" like this:

```
def encode_url(url):
    return url.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "#") + ".png"
```

I also wanted to be able to decode the filename to the original url:

```
def decode_filename(filename):
    n_url = ""
    for i in filename:
        if i == "#":
            n_url += ":"
        elif i == "_":
            n_url += "/"
        else:
            n_url += i
    return n_url
```

However, this will not work if the url is:

> "https://example.com/example_example_example"

I need a encoding and decoding method that doesn't go over character limit that works on any given url. (If that exists)

**The issue with base64 or hex encoding is that urls often exceed the character limit 255.**

I am making a monitorer application in python that records changes of sites. I am comparing changes in images. I am storing the links in json in a config.json and then storing the images in a folder with the encode_url() method.

When the user deletes a link, it needs to be deleted from config.json and the folder containing the image. I am therefore needing the method to encode the url to be reversebale in order to delete the image file.

If there are better solutions than this, I would also accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def encode_url(url):
    return url.replace("/", "$").replace(":", "#") + ".png"

def decode_filename(filename):
    return filename.replace('#',':').replace('$','_')
```

Comment: Haha, I did not think of the character "$". Thank you:)

Comment: In fact, you can use any UTF-16 character except /\:*"?<>| as well as NUL

Comment: Two big issues! 

1. There are many other characters not appropriate for filenames: https://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/websites/writing/characters-avoid/

2. The decode fails on URLs that contain `$` or `#`